# How can I develop my own cloud storage with access to other users like Google Drive but much simpler?

Tags: google-drive-api, cloud, google-cloud-storage, cloud-storage

My problem is that I need to build a cloud storage for my customers/clients/users, who can log in to my Cloud Storage Service.

I need to understand how they work in the back end, or how they’re developed, or how can I build my solution using a server, where I can thin provision my hard drive, let users see their data, etc. What resources and articles, along with the required skills, can I use? Or is there a software like WordPress is for websites?

Some additional points to better understand the problem:

How does Google Drive or Dropbox work in the background? Do they create a folder directory or a disk drive partition for each user?

Some of what I have in my mind: I develop a website where users purchase a plan of say 10 GB. The site then sends the userId, password, plan information to my Cloud Server, where I can assign storage to him.

At first, I thought to solve the problem with a root folder, where each new user will have a folder of his own. But that's where I found my first stumbling block: how to assign a size limit to a folder?

I also need to use the free storage (that the user is not using) to allocate to other users. And I don't think that can be done in directories (correct me if I'm wrong).

So far, I've searched about cloud storage, folder sizing, thin provisioning, public cloud, private cloud, etc. Most of the courses I've found so far teach about Amazon, Google, etc. However, I need to host my own cloud service.

Someone suggested to use Nextcloud or Syncthing, but they are not what I'm looking for (according to my understanding).

1- Syncthing works off of a peer-to-peer architecture rather than a client-server architecture.

2- NextCloud, from what I get, offers cloud storage for myself.

I apologize for the long post, but I'm in a real bind here. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Nextcloud does what you want. You can create group folders and give permissions to registered users or groups. You can share files or folders with external users. It is not only for single private users. You have NC instances with 1000's of users or more

Comment: I believe that is only possible on Enterprise Edition. Is there a course or guide to create it manually? Or with more low to no cost? It's only a university project.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [Filestack](https://www.filestack.com/). You can manage your files in your web application and can be used for web, mobile or desktop environment. It has the typical features of a common clout storage like Google Drive but has other functions like metadata, image transformations and can integrate into various frameworks as well. It also has a pretty simple user interface that your users can easily familiarize themselves with.